# How to make controller method sensitive to hex numbers in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, http, hex

Write own simple API using Spring. And a few days ago noticed this `not a bug, but a feature`.
Controller method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/author/{authorId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAuthor(@PathVariable Long authorId) {
    AuthorDto response = authorService.findAuthorByAuthorId(authorId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This `http://localhost:8080/api/library/author/0x2090` and `http://localhost:8080/api/library/author/8336` will return the same object.

Hex number `0x2090` will be converted to decimal as `8336`.

How to check it and make controller sensitive for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to use regex in path mapping :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class FooController {
    @GetMapping("/{id:[\\d]+}")
    public String foo(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return "not hex";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id:0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+}")
    public String fooHex(@PathVariable String id) {
        return "hex";
    }
}
```

/test/8336 will point to foo method as well as /test/0x2090 will point to fooHex method. I used number and hex number regex here.

Comment: Wow, great idea (y)

Comment: Yes, looks good. But, I think it is not the best solution... I have near 10 endpoints that use some Id on get, post, delete and put operations... Count of my endpoints will multiply on 2... One for Long and one for String

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this would be to make the `authorId` of type `String`, rename it to authorIdStri and then check its format:

```java
try {
            if (authorIdString.startsWith("0x")) {
                // hex number
                String hexString = authorIdString.substring(2);
                BigInteger h = new BigInteger(hexString, 16);
                userId = h.longValue();
            } else {
                // decimal number
                userId = Long.parseLong(possibleHexString);
            }

            if (userId == -1) {
                // value could not be parsed
                throw new NumberFormatException();
            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // ...
        }

        System.out.println(userId);
        // here you have your number
```

Although it's no that elegant, I hope it helps you.